# Join SQL with NoSQL databases

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I just wanted to know does it will make any sense to join sql database with nosql database?

Comment: What do you mean with "JOIN"? Most relational DBMS also support NoSQL features nowadays, e.g. (mainly) JSON but some also offer e.g. key/value storage or arrays

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i mean to make join from sql table to no-sql table does it make any sense technically or its there any other way i can think of.

Comment: That would require a system that can access both database servers at the same time and then implement a join strategy between those two systems. Most relational database offer some kind of technology to access remote database tables located in other systems - but they typically only support other relational systems. I know only of such an adapter in Postgres that can access a MongoDB instance and bring the data together inside the Postgres server. Does it make sense? Hard to say. Probably only for a very narrow use case

Answer (score -1):

Yes it makes sense, one of the big advantage of NoSQL data storage is that data is not tight to specific schema.

One fundamental difference between SQL and NOSQL dB's is support for transactions.

Imagine you were writing a banking app that keeps account balances. You will not be able to achieve accurate balance values unless you use transactions. This is common in all SQL dbs that support ACID semantics.

However support for transactions is not available in NOSql. Therefore NOSql is not suited for any project that needs transactions.

That said, if the same banking app needs tremendous scale, it can be built such that all non transactional data or data that can tolerate "eventual consistency" can use NOSql and data that needs transaction support can be stored in an SQL db.

The advantage of this design would be the benefit of automatic sharding or splitting of data that NOSql DBs provide that allows them to scale easily. In effect, maintenance needs of the DB can be significantly reduced by choosing for a hybrid model such as this.